# Camel 3.x and JBoss Fuse tools compatibility

Tags: eclipse-plugin, apache-camel, jbossfuse

We have upgraded a Camel 2.x project to Camel 3.x. We are using Spring DSL to describe the camel context content and we use the Eclipse JBoss Fuse tool plugin to configure the routes graphically. After migrating to Camel 3.x, and using the latest JBoss fuse eclipse plugin, the graphical view of the routes only shows the route objects with an warning:  "Parameter input is a mandatory field and cannot be empty.". Dragging components onto the routes does not work either.
We think that the Camel 3.x versions are not compatible with the current JBoss fuse tools. Is his the case ? If so is there a roadmap to support Camel 3.x via the JBoss Fuse tools ?

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, the current Eclipse Jboss Tools Fuse Tooling is not compatible with Camel 3.x.
There is currently no plan to upgrade it as there was no demand for it so far.

you can vote/comment on https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-fuse/issues/1737